# Vue.js: Alternative index for v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

https://jsfiddle.net/4faecf49a1e9/Lmbkdpc2/

```html
<div id="nest">

  <h2>Fill input for blocks appearance or disappearance</h2>
  <div id="element_inputs">
    <input v-for="net, index in elements" v-model="elements[index].value" />
  </div>

  <div id="elements_render">
    <div v-for="bl, index in elements_list" v-if="elements[bl].value !== ''" :style="{ 'backgroundColor': colors_list[index] }" class="block">{{index}}</div>
  </div>

  <h2>Write colors here (example: yellow, pink, orange)</h2>
  <input id="colors" type="" name="" v-model="recoloring" />
</div>
```

```js
var lay = new Vue({
  el: '#nest',
  props: ["recoloring"],
  data: {
    elements: {
      'box1': { value: 'first' },
      'box2': { value: '' },
      'box3': { value: '' },
      'box4': { value: '' }
    },
    elements_list: ['box1', 'box2', 'box3', 'box4'],
    colors_list: []
  },
  watch: {
    recoloring: function (arg) {
      this.colors_list = arg.split(',')
    }
  }
});
```

I'm trying to create appearance of blocks if their linked input is filled (we do not render blocks if their input is empty).
This work was done but long time I stuck with a problem of ”correct“ coloring of the blocks when people can create own list of colors inside special input.
As example you write "yellow, pink, orange" in this input and fill 1,2 and 4 inputs for these blocks appearance (v-if). 3 input is empty so it cant be showed. Problem is that I get 1 and 2 recolored but 4 has default color because recoloring affect hidden 3 block while I need first 3 in order (without matter of 3 existence). I cant go in this job along default index.
In this case if I fill 3 input after 4 must lose color and "give" it to block before (3) while I do not write new color after orange as example "yellow, pink, orange, blue"

How I can do that? What I can do with index?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work as expected? https://jsfiddle.net/n5c1q9tk/